# Confusion about python unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have writen a python file in windows7 by sublime text, there are some Chinese characters in the file, so when I run it, the characters become unrecognizable (the same occurs in cmd and git bash):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
str = "测试"

print str

arr = []
arr.append(str)

print arr
```

the result is:

```
娴嬭瘯
['\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe8\xaf\x95']
```

How can I solve this problem? what is the cause of this problem? and the `arr` print result shouldn't be unicode like `\uXXX`?

By the way, without the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` I can't even run it:

```
$ python test.py
  File "test.py", line 2
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe6' in file test.py on line 2, but no encodi
ng declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

I just googled the statement， why can't the code run without it?

Comment: What version of Python are you running this on?

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey: 2.7.5

Comment: Since unicode handling is different in 3, I'll add Python 2.7 as a tag.

Comment: Which encoding is used by your terminal?

Comment: The lack of a `\uXXX` is because it isn't an unicode string, but a byte sequence. Prepend a `u` to `"测试"` for an unicode string.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I'm not sure, how can I know it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing the UTF-8-encoded version of your string (which you shouldn't name `str`, by the way). By adding the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` line at the start of your script, you're telling Python that that's the encoding your script is using. Are you *sure* that it is in fact using that encoding?

If that's not the case (check your editor!) or if your terminal window (where you're `print`ing the string) happens to be using a different encoding, you'll get gibberish (or errors if the encoded string can't be interpreted in that encoding).

Only if you *decode* your (byte)string, you'll get a Unicode object.

So first you need to know your terminal's character encoding. Then you should be converting all strings to Unicode as soon as possible and manipulate only Unicode objects in your program until it's time to output them - at which point you need to encode them to the correct encoding.

For example

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
s = u"测试"
s = s + u"娴嬭瘯"
print s.encode("somecodepage")
```

Answer (score 4):

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is needed to [specify the encoding](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) used in file.

You're getting `['\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe8\xaf\x95']` as output because your string is a byte string not a unicode string, add a `u` prefix to the string to convert it to a unicode string.

```
>>> strs = u"测试"
>>> lis = [strs]
>>> print lis
[u'\u6d4b\u8bd5']
>>> print lis[0]
测试
```